# Observable <boolean> dont return java value

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, observable

iam trying to make a request for backend for a boolean value with observable but i cant get there, dont know what is the best option .map .subscribe

```
return this.http.put({url}, credentials, this.requestOptions)
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.message)).map((res...
```

the call is to a api that returns boolean

```
    @PutMapping("/url")
public Boolean api(@RequestBody Credentials credentials)
```

how can i get that boolean value back in typescript?

Comment: Do you subscribe to the observable?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the angular httpClient `.put(...)` usually takes a generic parameter to tell the observable returned that the observable resolves to that type this is simply to make it type safe.

Your issue in addition might be regarding subscribing to the observable.

Note: remember that the `http.put` returns an Observable which means it will not do anything until subscribed to.